# How to sum all the items in stack? Postfix calculator

Tags: c++, stack, postfix-notation

I'm making a postfix calculator and I want to make a new feature to it. How can I sum all the items in a stack and then delete the items used for summing from the stack and then push the sum back to the stack? All this should happen by pressing command 's'.

I tried doing it like this but it always prints me just 0.

```cpp
    case 's':
        if (numbers.top().first == underflow)
            cout << "Stack empty" << endl;
        else {
            numbers.pop();
            if (numbers.top().first == underflow) {
                cout << "Stack has just one entry" << endl;
                numbers.push(p);
            }

            else {
                while (!numbers.empty()) {
                    sum += numbers.top().second;

                }
                numbers.push(sum);
                cout << sum << endl;

            }
        }
        break;
```

Here is some code of my main.cpp.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "Stack.h"
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

void help()
{
    cout
        << "[?]push to stack [=]print top [x]exchange [s]sum [a]average" << endl
        << "[+] [-] [*] [/] [%] [^] [v] are arithmetic operations" << endl
        << "[Q]uit." << endl;
}

char get_command()
{
    char command;
    bool waiting = true;
    cout 
        << "Select command and press <Enter>:" << endl;

    while (waiting) {
        cin >> command;
        command = tolower(command);
        if (command == '?' || command == '=' || command == '+' ||
            command == '-' || command == '*' || command == '/' ||
            command == 'q' || command == 'x' || command == 's' || 
            command == 'a' || command == '%' || command == '^' || 
            command == 'v') waiting = false;


        else {
            cout << "Please enter a valid command:" << endl;
        }
    }
    return command;
}


bool do_command(char command, Stack& numbers)

{
    double p, q, g, r;
    double sum = 0;
    switch (command) {
    case '?':
        cout << "Enter a real number: " << flush;
        cin >> p;
        if (numbers.push(p) == overflow)
            cout << "Warning: Stack full, lost number" << endl;
        break;

    case '=':
        if (numbers.top().first == underflow)
            cout << "Stack empty" << endl;
        else
            cout << p << endl;
        break;

    case '+':
        if (numbers.top().first == underflow)
            cout << "Stack empty" << endl;
        else {
            numbers.pop();
            if (numbers.top().first == underflow) {
                cout << "Stack has just one entry" << endl;
                numbers.push(p);
            }

            else {
                numbers.pop();
                if (numbers.push(q + p) == overflow)
                    cout << "Warning: Stack full, lost result" << endl;
            }
        }
        break;

    case '-':
        if (numbers.top().first == underflow)
            cout << "Stack empty" << endl;
        else {
            numbers.pop();
            if (numbers.top().first == underflow) {
                cout << "Stack has just one entry" << endl;
                numbers.push(p);
            }

            else {
                numbers.pop();
                if (numbers.push(q - p) == overflow)
                    cout << "Warning: Stack full, lost result" << endl;
            }
        }
        break;

    case '*':
        if (numbers.top().first == underflow)
            cout << "Stack empty" << endl;
        else {
            numbers.pop();
            if (numbers.top().first == underflow) {
                cout << "Stack has just one entry" << endl;
                numbers.push(p);
            }

            else {
                numbers.pop();
                if (numbers.push(q * p) == overflow)
                    cout << "Warning: Stack full, lost result" << endl;
            }
        }
        break;

    case '/':
        if (numbers.top().first == underflow)
            cout << "Stack empty" << endl;
        else {
            numbers.pop();
            if (numbers.top().first == underflow) {
                cout << "Stack has just one entry" << endl;
                numbers.push(p);
            }

            else {
                numbers.pop();
                if (numbers.push(q / p) == overflow)
                    cout << "Warning: Stack full, lost result" << endl;
            }
        }
        break;

    case 'x':
        if (numbers.top().first == underflow)
            cout << "Stack empty" << endl;
        else {
            numbers.pop();
            if (numbers.top().first == underflow) {
                cout << "Stack has just one entry" << endl;
                numbers.push(p);
            }

            else {
                numbers.pop();
                numbers.pop();
                numbers.push(p);
                numbers.push(q);
            }
        }
        break;

    case 's':
        if (numbers.top().first == underflow)
            cout << "Stack empty" << endl;
        else {
            numbers.pop();
            if (numbers.top().first == underflow) {
                cout << "Stack has just one entry" << endl;
                numbers.push(p);
            }

            else {
                while (!numbers.empty()) {
                    sum += numbers.top().second;

                }
                numbers.push(sum);
                cout << sum << endl;

            }
        }
        break;
```

Here is my Stack.cpp.

```cpp
Error_code Stack::push(const Stack_entry& item)
/*
Pre:  None.
Post: If the Stack is not full, item is added to the top
      of the Stack.  If the Stack is full,
      an Error_code of overflow is returned and the Stack is left unchanged.
*/

{
    Error_code outcome = success;
    if (count >= maxstack)
        outcome = overflow;
    else
        entry[count++] = item;
    return outcome;
}


Error_code Stack::pop()
/*
Pre:  None.
Post: If the Stack is not empty, the top of
      the Stack is removed.  If the Stack
      is empty, an Error_code of underflow is returned.
*/

{
    Error_code outcome = success;
    if (count == 0)
        outcome = underflow;
    else --count;
    return outcome;
}


pair<Error_code, int> Stack::top() const
{
    pair<Error_code, int> p;
    Error_code outcome = success;
    if (count == 0) 
        p.first = underflow;
        p.second = 0;
        return p;

    p.first = outcome;
    p.second = entry[count - 1];
    return p;
}
```

Here is my Stack.h

```cpp
#include "Utility.h"

typedef double Stack_entry;

const int maxstack = 10;

class Stack {
public:
    Stack();
    bool empty() const;
    Error_code pop();
    //Error_code top(Stack_entry& item) const;
    Error_code push(const Stack_entry& item);
    //Error_code pop_top(Stack& s, Stack_entry& item);
    double size() const; 
    std::pair<Error_code, int> top() const;

private:
    int count;
    Stack_entry entry[maxstack];
};
```

I would expect it to sum all the numbers in the stack together and then deleting them and then pushing it back to the stack. I would really appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

`pop` doesn't return value like other languages in C++. You need to use `top` function for returning top element in stack. You can add that element to sum, then remove it with `pop`. You can implement it as below:

```
while (!numbers.empty()) 
{
    sum += numbers.top();
    numbers.pop()
}
```

For Op's another request:

Change `top`'s implementation to this:

```
std::pair<Error_code,int> top() const
    {
        std::pair<Error_code,int> p;
        Error_code outcome = success;
        if (count == 0)
            p.first = underflow;
            p.second = 0;
            return p;

        p.first = outcome;
        p.second = entry[count -1];
        return p;
    }
```

And your first problem's solution becomes this:

```
while (!numbers.empty()) 
    {
        sum += numbers.top().second;
        numbers.pop()
    }
```

if you want `outcome` you can do `numbers.top().first`. That's all.

Comment: Thanks but the problem is that the top() function requires a parameter and no matter what I put there I just get 0. @Marceline

Comment: But why it requires a paramater? If it does, `top` function becomes meaningless.

Comment: This is a homework of ours and the idea is to use the functions that are already made. Can you see any other way to do it? @Marceline

Comment: As you can see, there is nothing you can do to get element from that stack implementation because that stack implementation's operations only return `Error_code`, not value. You can change `top`'s return type to pair (so you can return outcome as well as value. If the implementation is forbidden to change, there is nothing you can do. If it is not forbidden, inform me. I will edit my answer.

Comment: Okay, thank you so much for helping me. I think editing the functions isn't forbidden so you can change it if you want. @Marceline

Comment: The code above is edited code now. I tried but now it's giving an error
C4700 uninitialized local variable 'q' used main.cpp line 71. Any ideas what is the problem? @Marceline

Comment: Your `top` function's if block is not like mine. Indentation is wrong, try to correct it.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand what you mean? @Marceline

Comment: In your `top` function, `p.second = 0` and `return p` must be in if block but if you control yourself, yours is not. Try to correct it.

Comment: Also you declared `q` but did not assign any value to it and used it so it gave error. You need to make assignment to `q` if you want to use it.

Comment: I edited the code again can you check if it's now correct? I tried to assign 0 to the q but then it gives me 0 as an answer when I try to calculate something. @Marceline

Comment: Your problem is differrent than before. My answer must be solved your problem so you can mark as accepted answer. If you want to ask further questions you can ask in another post because we can not transform this comment thread into chat. Hope you do well.